# Are the binaries in this snippet launched sequentially or parallel?

Tags: bash, shell

I have this code snippet:

```bash
gnome-terminal --tab -t "ABC" -e "bash -c 'cd $PWD/ABC/binary_folder; ./ABC lo;bash'" \
    --tab -t "XYZ" -e "bash -c 'cd $PWD/XYZ/binary_folder; ./XYZ lo; bash'" \
```

Will the two executables `ABC` and `XYZ` be started in parallel, or is `ABC` started first, followed by `XYZ`?

Comment: This seems to be *one* command line (which starts `gnome-terminal` with some command line arguments). I'm not sure what the trailing backslash will do.

Comment: The question to this rather depends on what `gnome-terminal` does. In general, if you have a dependency like that and there are no guarantees, you have a race condition (a bug).

Comment: The question is therefore in which order `gnome-terminal` will start programs assigned to multiple tabs on its command line. I would think that this is not documented (neither in the [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html) nor in the [gnome documentation](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/gs-tabs.html.en)). As an aside, `-e` is deprecated, and you seem to use it in a non-standard way (without `=`), and the relationship between multiple `-e` and `--tab` is not documented.

Comment: That said, I would expect the behavior to be consistent: The tabs are either created left-to-right or right-to-left and begin to execute their respective commands. The programs on different tabs will be executed in parallel (i.e., tab 2 with its associated command will be created before the command associated with tab1 has terminated), and the tab creation will be so fast that the two commands will appear to run essentially in parallel as well.

Comment: Now the question is: What is your *actual* problem? ;-)

Comment: Maybe change the command to print the time, and see if one is consistently sooner. Or use `touch` to change the timestamp of the same file to 2 different dates by the 2 processes and see which one wins.

Comment: `bash -c /path/to/folder; other-command` doesn't do what you think it does. The `bash` command privately changes directory in its own process and then terminates. The directory change is lost; the `other-command` executes in the original directory.

Comment: Hi All , Thanks for all your replies . My issue is that , I am working on networking , and the 2 binaries start two separate entities , in 2 parallel tabs and each of them is a server and client entity . The first one ABC is a server entity , and XYZ is a client entity . As soon as XYZ comes up , it will send connection request to ABC , but for 1st few ms , it finds ABC unreachable . After retry , XYZ can send connection request to ABC . ABC being a server is supposed to come up first . But that is where I am confused . . ... ( continued in next comment)

Comment: ..... They do open in 2 parallel tabs and run in parallel . But my question is , does ABC tab open up first followed by XYZ opening up after few ms , or do both tabs open up at the exact same instant of time ? ....Regards, Thanks for helping .

Comment: Why don't you measure it, like I suggested?